# Securing a Meteor Chat

Tags: javascript, security, meteor, chat

I have a simple chat created by inserting messages into a collection and having a template print out the collection with {{#each}}.

I'm not well versed in security, but would there be a way to get this up to par with the EFF regulations?

https://www.eff.org/secure-messaging-scorecard

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the first 4 parts here are my thoughts. I consider the 3 last ones as something that depends on you (I assume that the meteor part is covered).

1. Encrypted in transit?

You would need to add an https proxy. That's not a big deal.

2. Encrypted so the provider can’t read it?

As far as I know, [it should be possible to use a package to ensure that](https://github.com/strikeout/mylar).

3. Can you verify contacts’ identities?

That's a built-in meteor feature (see accounts-base and accounts-password package). You keep track of your users authentication with security tokens. You can make make a public ID out of it and allow the user to check it as described on EFF

4. Are past communications secure if your keys are stolen?

I am not entirely sure about this one, but I guess it has to do with the security token validity time span.

Comment: Mylar indeed solves the hardest part for you - preventing the provider from getting access to your data.  Point #4 is referring to perfect forward secrecy.  Not sure if Mylar handles that....